# "The devil is in the detail" or "The devil is in details"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Which statement is correct?

> The devil is in the detail

Or,

> The devil is in details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "...detail" and "...details" are used, with near identical meaning.

When speaking of a single process it may be better to use the singular. When talking about a complex process, the plural seems better. Though this is not a strict rule and either phrase could be used in both of the examples below.

> Here is the contract from the lawyer. Please check it carefully; remember "the devil is in the detail".
>
> Preparing for a long expedition requires careful planning. It is true that "the devil is in the details", and each stage needs checking and rechecking.

Answer (score 3):

"The devil is in the detail" is a fixed idiom. You cannot change the words.

> "The devil is in the detail" is an idiom that refers to a catch or
>   mysterious element hidden in the details, meaning that something
>   might seem simple at a first look but will take more time and effort
>   to complete than expected and derives from the earlier phrase, "God is
>   in the detail" expressing the idea that whatever one does should be
>   done thoroughly; i.e. details are important.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_devil_is_in_the_detail

Comment: You can't say that "you cannot change the words" and then link to a wikipedia article that says that there are multiple variants of the idiom!  If you check [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=devil+is+in+the+detail%2Cdevil+is+in+the+details&year_start=1900&year_end=2010), you'll see that the version with the plural **details** is the most popular, although that seems to be the case specifically in American English.  In BrE, the singular is slightly more popular.

Answer (score 1):

Both the singular *and* the plural form are used. So, while this may be a *fixed* idiom, it's one that isn't specifically fixed to either the singular or the plural.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/devil_is_in_the_details):

> In allusion to *God is in the detail*.
>
> **(the) devil is in the details**
>
> (idiomatic) The specific provisions of, or particular steps for implementing, a general plan, policy, or contract may be complicated, controversial, or unworkable.
>
> [But also:]
>
> **Usage notes**
>   "Detail" as a mass noun is also used instead of "details" - *The devil is in the detail.*

[The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/the-devil-is-in-the-details.html):

> The source of the proverb 'The devil is in the details' is often attributed to the German/American architect Ludwig Mies Van Der Rohe. This is almost certainly a misattribution. The expression derives from an earlier German proverb - "Der liebe Gott steckt im detail", which translates as 'God is in the detail'. Mies Van Der Rohe is also associated with this earlier form but, although he may have used it, there's no evidence that he was the first to do so.
>
> In the migration of the phrases an 's' was added - the earlier form is usually 'God is in the detail'; the later form is more commonly 'the devil is in the details'.
>
> 'The devil is in the details' only came into common use in the 1990s (Van Der Rohe died in 1969) and the earliest citation of it that I've found in print is in Richard Mayne's explanation of the workings of the European Union - The Community of Europe, 1963:
>
> > On the principle that ‘the devil is in the details’, what should have been a merely formal occasion developed into a debate about the Community's official languages and the site of its headquarters.

[Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/words/devil-is-in-the-details-vs-god-is-in-the-detail/):

> The idiom **the devil is in the details** means that mistakes are usually made in the small details of a project. Usually it is a caution to pay attention to avoid failure.
>
> An older, and slightly more common, phrase **God is in the detail** means that attention paid to small things has big rewards, or that details are important.

From Elyse Bruce's article ["The Devil Is in the Details"](https://idiomation.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/the-devil-is-in-the-details/) at Historically Speaking:

> And in 1937, German architect, poet, and writer, Erhard Horst Bellermann was quoted as saying *the devil is in the details*. But even he wasn’t the first to use this expression. Jumping back to two more generations, German philologist, philosopher, cultural critic, poet and composer, Friedrich Wilhelm Nietzsche (15 October 1844 – 25 August 1900) is quoted as having said, “*Der Teufel steckt im Detail*” which translates directly to “*the devil is in the details*.”
>
> This expression is found in a number of countries and is identified as a proverb. Italians know it as *Il diavolo sta nei dettagli* and the Spanish know it as *El diablo está en los detalles*. The Brasilians say *O diabo está nos detalhes*, while the Turks say *Şeytan ayrıntıda gizlidir*. However, at the same as this expression was being said in countries around the world, an opposite idiom was also being said.

---

I would say that you are free to use either the singular or the plural form.

However, [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=devil%20is%20in%20the%20detail%2C%20devil%20is%20in%20the%20details&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdevil%20is%20in%20the%20detail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdevil%20is%20in%20the%20details%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdevil%20is%20in%20the%20detail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdevil%20is%20in%20the%20details%3B%2Cc0) suggests that the plural form (in writing) is more common:

[image: devil is in the details]

Note, however, that this shows combined US and UK usage. If you switch the corpus to just [UK English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=devil%20is%20in%20the%20detail%2Cdevil%20is%20in%20the%20details&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdevil%20is%20in%20the%20detail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdevil%20is%20in%20the%20details%3B%2Cc0), the singular becomes the more common (although only slightly):

[image: devil is in the details (UK)]

Answer (score 0):

**The devil is in the detail** is an idiom meaning **that something might seem simple at a first look but will take more time and effort to complete than expected**.

 [**The devil is in the detail**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_devil_is_in_the_detail%20%20%20)